# Selecting data from two tables using Mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql

I have to select data from two tables with following criteria,

lets say there are two tables as,,

**Table one**

```
id | itemName | Quantity | companyName

1    bread      25         the Baker pvt ltd
2    butter     30         green famers
```

**Table two**

```
id | itemName | itemPrice

1    bread      30.50      
6    jam        80.25
```

what I need is,

select items out of two tables which their ids are matching and the quantities of them should be multiplied by the unit price if ids are matching. The rows which don't have matching ids should be selected but their quantities should not multiplied.

Comment: Where is the unit price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT o.id, o.itemName, o.companyName, o.Quantity * IFNULL(t.itemPrice, 1) total
     FROM one o
LEFT JOIN two t 
       ON o.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work ...

```
Select a.id, a.itemName, a.companyName, a.Quantity * IFNULL(b.itemPrice,1) As total
From table1 as a 
Left Join table2 as b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: thanx a lot for your answer, with this query i can get all the rows that the id is match, when there is no matching ids of each tables how can I select them also?

Comment: I think I get what you mean.  I think you want a FULL OUTER JOIN instead then.  This will return data from both tables even if there is no match.  You'll want to add a few more columns in if this is the case because if the LHS table doesn't have a match, you will have NULL for all values currently being selected.